# How to add images in steps using primeNG for Angular8?

Tags: primeng

I have tried

```
import {StepsModule} from 'primeng/steps';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

<p-steps [model]="items"></p-steps>

export class MenuDemo {

    items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {label: 'Step 1',icon : pi pi-fw postajob-icon},
            {label: 'Step 2'},
            {label: 'Step 3'}
        ];
    }
}
```

But it's not working
I want the image below the step number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it is currently not possible to include the images / icon in the steps component.

However, you can achieve it in a different way ( bit of hacky way!! )

**Step 1:** Make sure you have the proper image files `.svg or .png` in your assets folder. You can also load directly from CDN or online if you prefer.

**Step 2:** In your component.scss or .css file

**Note:** `:host::ng-deep` is for overriding styles.

```
:host::ng-deep {
    .ui-steps.ui-steps-readonly .ui-steps-item {
        background-image: url('./../../../assets/android.svg'); //my img file 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 30px, 30px, contain;
        background-position: center 80px;
    }
    .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link {
        padding-bottom: 55px; //to display properly. Adjust it if needed 
    }
    body .ui-steps:before {
        top: 31%;  // to display the line properly 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

PS: you can adjust the css property to display the image wherever you like.

Also for your convenience, I have create the functional example in stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbcxxv

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ragavan,Thanks for the reply ,will try it and let you know

Comment: Sure no worries. Pls check the functional example for working version

Comment: Hi there, happy that I could help you! You may also upvote the answer if you think it was helpful! Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, Raghavan,The Answer was helpful :)

Comment: Hi Raghavan,I have a similar kind of problem,I want to remove numbers of stpes, but I am not able to do it.Kindly Help me out.Regards